# How to overwrite the same sheet with new data after updating a new csv file to G drive using Google Apps Script

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

Firstly, after uploading a new .csv file, i execute the script. Then the .csv file will convert to Google Sheets in a Google Drive folder. The problem I am facing right now is when i delete the .csv file and upload a another .csv file, it is creating a new sheet. How can I update the same sheet after i upload a new .csv file?

[image]

So far, this code will convert whatever .csv file to sheets in the folder. I am not sure how to overwrite the sheet when I reupload another .csv file with same name. i dont want the script to create another sheet when i upload a new .csv file

```
function convert() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    Drive.Files.copy({}, file.getId(), {convert: true});
  }
}
```

I want the .csv file that I have uploaded to overwrite the existing sheet in Google Drive

Comment: Can you explain about your script in your question? And can you explain about the relationship between your script and your issue?

Comment: There is no issue in script right now. The script is converting the .csv file to sheet. But when i delete the .csv and reupload it with different data with same .csv file, it is creating another sheet. i want it to overwrite the existing sheet. I am not sure how to that function

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating it. About `same name` you say, in your situation, the filenames of CSV file and Google Spreadsheet are the same. When the filename of CSV file is `sample.csv`, the filename of Spreadsheet is also `sample.csv`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: And, in your situation, the CSV files and the converted Google Spreadsheet are put in the same folder. So when the same filenames of CSV file and Spreadsheet are found, you want to overwrite the CSV data to the Spreadsheet of the same name. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes exactly. So now when i re upload the sample,csv with new data, the sample spreadsheet must be updated

Comment: How about the filename? I cannot understand about `same name` you say. Can you explain about this?

Comment: I have uploaded the image of my folder. When I delete the .csv file and reupload again with the same .csv file, it will create another copy of C3 Status. I just want it to overwrite the C3 Status sheet.

Comment: Can you understand what I m trying to say.

Comment: I cannot understand about `When I delete the .csv file and reupload again with the same .csv file, it will create another copy of C3 Status.`. For example, when the CSV file of `sample.csv` is uploaded after the CSV file of `sample.csv` is deleted, the filename of uploaded CSV file is changed from `sample.csv` to other. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No it wont change. It will create another spreadsheet. I just want one spreadsheet. The spreadsheet must overwrite. It must not create another one.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? At first, please confirm whether my understanding for your goal is correct. If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- CSV files and Google Spreadsheet files are put in the same folder.
- Filename of CSV file has the extension of `.csv`. But the filename of Spreadsheet has not extension. For example, you want to use the filenames of `sample.csv` of CSV file and `sample` of Spreadsheet as the same filename.
- When there is only one filename of CSV file in the folder, you want to convert CSV file to Spreadsheet as new Spreadsheet.
- When there is the same filename of CSV file and Spreadsheet in the folder, you want to overwrite the CSV file to the existing Spreadsheet.
- After creating and overwriting files are done, you want to delete all CSV files in the folder.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? The flow of modified script is as follows. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve all files in the specific folder.
2. Create an object for processing files.

   - In this case, `{create: [], overWrite: [], deleteCsvFiles: []}` is created.
3. If there are files for converting to new Spreadsheet, those CSV files are converted to new Spreadsheet.
4. If there are files for overwriting the existing Spreadsheet, the existing Spreadsheet files are overwritten by the CSV files.
5. All CSV files in the folder are deleted.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, please set the variable of `folderId`. And then, please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google Services, again.

```
function convert() {
  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID here.

  // Retrieve all files in the folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var fileList = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    fileList.push({
      id: file.getId(),
      name: file.getName().split(".")[0],
      mimeType: file.getMimeType()
    });
  }

  // Create an object for processing files
  var temp = {};
  var res = fileList.reduce(function(o, e, i) {
    if (e.mimeType == MimeType.CSV) o.deleteCsvFiles.push(e.id);
    if (e.name in temp) {
      if (temp[e.name].length == 2) throw new Error("Error");
      if (fileList[temp[e.name][0]].mimeType != e.mimeType) {
        o.overWrite.push({
          from: e.mimeType == MimeType.CSV ? e.id : fileList[temp[e.name][0]].id,
          to: e.mimeType == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS ? e.id : fileList[temp[e.name][0]].id,
        });
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error");
      }
      temp[e.name].push(i);
    } else {
      temp[e.name] = [i];
    }
    if (i == fileList.length - 1) {
      o.create = Object.keys(temp).reduce(function(ar, e) {
        if (temp[e].length == 1 && fileList[temp[e][0]].mimeType == MimeType.CSV) {
          ar.push(fileList[temp[e][0]]);
        }
        return ar;
      }, []);
    }
    return o;
  }, {create: [], overWrite: [], deleteCsvFiles: []});

  // Create new Spreadsheet from CSV file
  if (res.create.length > 0) {
    res.create.forEach(function(e) {
      Drive.Files.copy({}, e.id, {convert: true});
    });
  }

  // Overwrite Spreadsheet by CSV file
  if (res.overWrite.length > 0) {
    res.overWrite.forEach(function(e) {
      var mediaData = DriveApp.getFileById(e.from).getBlob();
      Drive.Files.update({}, e.to, mediaData);
    });
  }

  // // Delete CSV files
  // if (res.deleteCsvFiles.length > 0) {
  //   res.deleteCsvFiles.forEach(function(e) {
  //     Drive.Files.remove(e);
  //   });
  // }
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that the files of the same filename are only 2 files. When there are more than 3 files of the same filename, an error is thrown.
- When there are the files of the same filename and same mimeType, an error is thrown.
- When the file size of CSV file is large, the error might occur.
- **In the current stage, I commented out the script of "Delete CSV files". Because when this script is run, the CSV files are deleted. When you use this script, please be careful.**

#### References:

- [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update)
- [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/delete)

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thank you very much. U are The Best

Comment: @Sriram Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.